# Knowing coordinates of a point having two coordinates and the distance.

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates, spherical-coordinates

I have the two geographic coordinates of the lower corners of a wall. So, for example, i want to know what is the coordinate that is for example 15cm on the right of the lower corner left.

Is that possible having the coordinates of the lower corner?

Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your question: What do you mean by geographic coordinates? Lat, long, Alt?  If so, linear interpolation would be sufficiently accurate for distances of 15cm.

Comment: Use the haversine formula to account for the curvature of the earth.  Because you are doing this for 15cm I assume you work at CERN so it might also be a good idea to double check your cable connections.

Comment: Yes, i am using Lat, Long, Alt.